# Will there be any problem re-entering the US with a B-1/B-2 visa after four months away?

Tags: b1-b2-visas, repeat-visits, bangladeshi-citizens

I'm from Bangladesh. I have a B-1/B-2 visa valid till 24th July 2018. I had a short visit to USA from 1st-25th September, 2015. When I arrived they gave me six months till 29th Feb 2016, but I left on 25th September. Now I want to go back again for three weeks in February 2016.

Will there be any problem with my entry?

Comment: Why would there possibly be a problem here? This sounds perfectly normal.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I heard I have to wait at least 4-5 months. but Is it ok if I wanna re-enter after 3 months? I mean In January?

Comment: You can re-enter the day after you left if you wanted. There is no amount of time you must wait between visits.

Comment: Yes i know that but I heard the border officer can deny my entry..there are some rules..

Comment: Yes, you must not be trying to live in the US.

Comment: just to be more sure..I left us on 24th September 2015 . If I wanna visit again In Janu 2016? will I have a hard time in POE?

Comment: You have a visa. You can go back _today_ if your visit is consistent with the visa purpose (business or tourism).

Answer (score 1):

What can we say? There's never a guarantee you will be allowed into the USA. CBP can always deny entry. But in this case I would say you will be let in without a problem:

1. You already have a visa which you can only get if you prove significant enough ties to your home country.
2. Your visits are short and to me (who is not CBP, just this random stranger on the Internet) it seems you fulfill the "there should be a reasonable amount of time between visits so that the CBP Officer does not think you are trying to live here".
3. I presume you will have accommodations arranged and a return ticket to show.

Comment: Thank you so much.I will have return ticket with me . I'm willing to have a 3 weeks short visit. but I was worried  If they deny my entry cos i will try after 3 months of my previous visit.

Comment: Once again, I am not a CBP officer but three months between two trips both less than a month should be aplenty.